# Low-depth arithmetic complexity of the product of $k$ matrices

Tags: matrices, arithmetic-circuits, matrix-product, bounded-depth

Is anything known about the size of $\Sigma\Pi\Sigma$ (or other constant depth) circuits for the product of $k$ matrices?

Trivial upper bounds (up to small factors) are:

- if $k=2$, then there are $\Sigma\Pi\Sigma$ circuits of size
  $n^{\omega}$ (where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication exponent.)
- if $k>2$, then  there are $\Sigma\Pi\Sigma$ circuits of size 
  $n^{k+1}$.
- if $k>2$, then  there are $O(log(k))$-depth circuits of size 
  $n^{\omega}$.

Is it possible to construct circuits of size $n^{\omega}$ for every $k$, for some fixed depth? Is it even possible to beat the trivial construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about specifically depth-three lower bounds, but there has been a lot of depth-4 (and 5) lower bounds, usually assuming other constraints as well. For instance (and without any claim of exhaustivity):

- Hervé Fournier, Nutan Limaye, Guillaume Malod, and Srikanth Srinivasan. [Lower Bounds for Depth-4 Formulas Computing Iterated Matrix Multiplication](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~nutan/papers/imm-merged.pdf).
- Suryajith Chillara, Partha Mukhopadhyay. [Depth-4 Lower Bounds, Determinantal Complexity : A Unified Approach](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1640).
- Suman K. Bera, Amit Chakrabarti. [A Depth-Five Lower Bound for Iterated Matrix Multiplication](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2015/5062/).